# How to detect GOP struct from H264/HEVC bitstream?Can I get it from sps info?

Tags: h.264, bitstream

Is it possible to get gop struct from sps info? I need to know the num of b frames in a gop.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible without parsing the entire stream as ever GOP can have a different number of b frames.